What the heck does this mean: “Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment.”
I just got this message when trying to leave a fairly innocuous comment for an edit on a question:


“Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment.”

The only way I could submit this edit was by leaving no comment at all.
What’s happening? That never happened before.

No idea - but someone just asked the same thing on meta.se "Comment reserved for system use" when trying to edit with an edit summary

Resolved on this MSE post
